# Symfony2 Security login not working when using pbkdf2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use pbkdf2 for password in symfony2 application. But it does not work. If I change to plaintext or sha1 login works. Below is the code I am using. What am I doing wrong?

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:            pbkdf2
            hash_algorithm:       sha512
            encode_as_base64:     true
            iterations:           1000
```

**Code to set password**

```
$encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('pass', $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

Comment: is `Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User` correct?

Comment: Yes I can use same class for plaintext

Answer (score 3):

I was able find the reason myself. The password field length was 40 and password generated by pbkdf2 was more than 40 characters. So password which was stored in database was getting truncated. I increased the field length to make it work.